# Concatenating javascript files with different encodings

Tags: javascript, encoding, utf-8, ascii, concatenation

Is there a general/best practice approach on how to deal with multiple encodings? since the js code on my site is about the same for every page, putting everything into one file makes sense, however I've run into a lot of wierd issues since some files are UTF-8, some ASCII, some have CLRF and some RF endings.

**EDIT**
So far I've used cat, however as far as I'm aware cat keeps the original encoding in place.

Comment: You should probably describe what issues exactly you have run into. ASCII (i.e. characters with codes in the range 0-127) _is_ valid UTF-8, you cannot distinguish between the two, and it would not cause problems if concatenated with actual UTF-8 text. Javascript interprets both `CR` and `LF` as line terminators, so mixed line-ending styles should also not present any problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should definitely aim for a unified encoding across all your files; if UTF-8 files are among them, then UTF-8 is the way to go. ASCII isn't a problem here (ASCII is a subset of UTF-8, so you can concatenate UTF-8 and ASCII files without problems), but other encodings (latin-1 etc.) are. You definitely want to avoid mixed encodings within a single file.

You should also normalize your line endings (all CRLF or all LF, but not both; certainly not within a single file - that's just ugly). On Unix systems, LF is the standard, so that's probably what you should be using.

`cat` doesn't care about encodings at all, it just pastes the files together, so it *will* mess up if you concatenate files with different encodings/line endings.

Comment: JS does not care about line-ending style, as both `CR` and `LF` are considered line terminators ([ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf), section 7.3). The file might _look_ messed up, but JS should have no problem parsing it.

Comment: @lanzz: Certainly, but it's still ugly, and who knows if it's only JavaScript that needs to handle the file? Some text editors get horribly confused when presented with a mixed-linefeed file.

Comment: follow up question: what would you use for conversion? is iconv the way to go? does it really convert all the files? I've converted some ASCII files to UTF-8, however running `file` still displays it as ASCII.

Comment: You don't need to convert ASCII to UTF-8; any valid ASCII file is a valid UTF-8 file. Only other encodings (as I mentioned in my answer) will cause problems.

Comment: If youre doing it within js; File => textarea => textarea value